# Input Button Not Responding To CSS

Tags: html, css, macos

I have an input button that is supposed to be huge. However, with the current CSS, it only stretches wide. The height is not touched.

HTML:

```
<form action="feedback.cfm" method="POST">
    <input type="hidden" name="send" value="mail" />
    <input class="hugeButton" type="submit" value="Click Me To Send A SpreadSheet Report" />
</form>
```

CSS:

```
<style type="text/css">
    .hugeButton {
        width:100%;
        height:45%;
        font-size:x-large;
    }
    .hugeButton:hover {
        cursor:pointer;
    }
</style>
```

Now, if I add `border:none` to my `.hugeButton` class, the height property works.

So my question is: why does the border of an input button "disable" the height property?

NOTE: I am using Google Chrome.

Comment: This isn't a full answer, but you might have better luck styling <button type="submit"><span>Click Me To Send A Spreadsheet</span></button> instead of the input type="submit" syntax.

Comment: @JoshC so removing the border around my button input turns it into an inline button?

Comment: @jameslafferty I'm trying to figure out why removing the border around the button effects being able to resize it by height, when with a border, you cannot.

Comment: @RUJordan I mis-read the question. Retracted that. As for the border, I am not sure. However, you should note that 45% of a body of 0 is also 0. See http://jsfiddle.net/JoshC/uKpY6/

Comment: @JoshC setting it to pixels or % does not work. Both work when I set border:none.

Comment: @RUJordan See the example I just edited in.

Comment: @JoshC add in border:none to that css and you'll see what I mean

Comment: @RUJordan I am not seeing a difference. It works with and without. http://jsfiddle.net/JoshC/uKpY6/1/

Comment: Here is a little case study: http://codepen.io/johannesjo/pen/JHuqC

Comment: @RUJordan Here's another fiddle example, showing the alternative markup comparison, in addition to the border:none comparison: http://jsfiddle.net/jameslafferty/KDFBE/ It looks like setting border:none also sets -webkit-appearance: none.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to give the document a height since the height of your button will be relative to that of an ancestor. Add:

```
html,body,form {
    height:100%;
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/KP4Zs/)**

Comment: Uhh, that does not work. The button is still the normal height with the border. Without the border, it works.

Comment: It works fine. What browser are you using? Did you view the fiddle?

Comment: Chrome, and yes. I even edited my running script, and it did not change anything.

Comment: So  in the fiddle you don't see the button now taking up a proper height whereas before it didn't? What OS are you on? I just read your edits. Changing the border doesn't do anything based on the code you posted. Try a fiddle with it and you'll see.

Comment: Mac OSX, it looks like a normal button, except it's simply not height effected until I remove the border.

Answer (score 0):

I think this winds up getting pretty intricate. It seems that the default values for -webkit-appearance are what's at play here.

When I look at the elements panel in the dev tools, I see the following values for -webkit-appearance:

1. `<button>` (with border) : button
2. `<input type="submit">` (with border) : push-button
3. `<button>` or `<input type="submit">` (without button) : none

I think -webkit-appearance:push-button is the culprit.

See this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jameslafferty/KDFBE/